# Eclipse Milo 0.2.0: Support for writing custom datatypes

Tags: milo

I am evaluating Eclipse Milo 0.2.0 with the Unified Automation server and have successfully read&decoded my own custom structures (by registering appropriate codecs). However client.write keeps returning with status code Bad_WriteNotSupported. I could write the structure node with another client, though.
Does Milo not support writing custom structures yet? If not, when is this feature scheduled?
THX for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Milo Client SDK does support reading and writing custom structures. If they are registered correctly with the server you don't have to register them with Milo; it reads the datatype dictionaries from the server upon connecting.